# R & Knitr html output: Create collapsing and expanding header

Tags: html, css, r, knitr

### Use case

I use R and [Knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) a lot to produce long html reports. The reports contain headers by using the markdown `#` syntax. These headers give good orientation for the reader's navigation...

### Problem

... but the reports sometimes get very long. Scrolling from beginning to the end take very long time. Readers of the reports get annoyed seeing all the report content before reaching the relevant parts.

### Question

Is there a way to implement in Knitr a collapsing and expanding header element?
[image: Example]

### Requirements

- By default the header shall be collapsed. Only by clicking the contents below the header shall expand. This would tremendously help to keep the reports small in appearance and facilitate easy and fast navigation.
- In order to give the reader feedback of the state the header it shall represent it's state. I recommend something along the mechanism used in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Collapsing#.22autocollapse.22) (see image above).

Comment: The issue is going to be that you'll have to manually add the `show`/`hide` buttons after `knit`ing. You may want to just add a table of contents, [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662626/set-page-width-in-knitr-for-md-or-html-output).

Answer (score 4):

You can make elements collapse using Javascript. The `jQuery` JavaScript framework makes this reasonably easy via the `hide` and `show` methods.

In the folder that contains your `Rmd` template, create a subfolder named `script` and save the [jQuery file](http://jquery.com/download/) in it.  (Doesn't have to be there, but that's a reasonably standard location.)

Add this code near the top of your `Rmd` file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
```

For Markdown, the closing tag needs to be [on a separate line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754391/embed-javascript-in-markdown).

Alternatively, if your report is mostly going to be read on machines where there is internet access, you <del>can</del> [should](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) use a Google-hosted version of `jQuery`.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" >
</script>
```

Then add another script block for your collapsing logic.  The exact implementation is up to you; there [are](http://designgala.com/how-to-expand-collapse-toggle-div-layer-using-jquery/) [lots](http://webcloud.se/jQuery-Collapse/) [of](http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/expand.html) [examples](http://www.roseindia.net/ajax/jquery/hideShowElement.shtml) on the internet.

The key to making your collapsing/expanding logic simple is to make sure that the elements you are manipulating have a consistent class (or a pattern to their ids).

Comment: Looks like, the markdown syntax of Knitr (i.e. # for header level 1) will not easily combine with the jQuery techniques being suggested.