# Is it possible to show/hide table rows with markdown in R

Tags: javascript, html, r, dynamic

I output a html file using rmarkdown package. In the medium of html file, there is a big table which consumes a lot of page area, so I want to collapse the big table and allow the user to use the drop down to view the table. 
Do you have any methods to insert a dynamic table which can hide/show rows and output other tables and graphs(using markdown) together into one html file ?

Comment: Possibly duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699178/r-knitr-html-output-create-collapsing-and-expanding-header

Comment: Thank you. Yes, actually I use javascript to collapse the table, and markdown to output other tables and graphs, and paste them together into one html file. While I want to find a better method to implement this function directly.

Answer (score 0):

Would the following solution be an alternative solution for you?  I find it to be helpful to me anyway.  Share it with you, hopefully it is a trick.

https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/2

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.